# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addCls' of null

Tags: javascript, extjs4.2

The code is as follows- 
I know the error is because of this line-

```
    record.set("units",newVal);
```

But I am unable to figure out, what exactly the problem is.
Here goes the code-

```
    Ext.onReady(function(){

    Ext.require([ 'Ext.ux.CheckColumn']);


   Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
         storeId:'simpsonsStore',
         fields:['name', 'email', 'units', 'unitInformation'],
         data:{'items':[
      { 'check':false,'name': 'Lisa',   "units":"555-111-1224" , "unitInformation":"a,b,c,d" },
      { 'check':false,'name': 'Bart',   "units":"555-222-1234",  "unitInformation":"a,b,c,d"  },
      { 'check':false,'name': 'Homer',  "units":"555-222-1244", "unitInformation":"a,b,c,d"   },
      { 'check':false,'name': 'Marge',  "units":"555-222-1254" , "unitInformation":"a,b,c,d"  }
  ]},
  proxy: {
      type: 'memory',
      reader: {
          type: 'json',
          root: 'items'
      }
  }
 });

     var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
  title: 'Simpsons',
  renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
  tbar: [
    { xtype: 'button', text: 'Button 1',
      handler: function(btn){
        console.log(grid.getStore().getUpdatedRecords());
      }
    }
  ],
  store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
  viewConfig: {markDirty: false},
  columns: [
      {
        xtype:'checkcolumn' ,id:'check',dataIndex:'check', text:'Select',
        listeners:{
          checkchange:function(checkbox, rowIndex, checked, eOpts){
            if(checked==true){
              this.up('grid').getView().getRecord(rowIndex).dirty=true;
            }
          } 
        }
      },
      { text: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name' ,       flex : 1,},
      {
        text : 'Units',
        flex : 1,
        dataIndex : 'units',
        xtype: 'componentcolumn',
        renderer: function(value, m, record) { 
          record.dirty=false;
          if(record.get('unitInformation')==='')    
            return '';
            return {
              listeners : {
                change: function(combo,newVal,oldVal,opts) {
                  record.set("units",newVal);
                  if(record.get('check')==true)
                    record.dirty=true;
                  else
                    record.dirty=false;
                }
              },
              store: record.get('unitInformation').split(","), 
                value: value, 
                xtype: 'combobox' 
            };
          }
        }],
  buttons:[{
      text:'Create Button',
      handler:function(btn){

        var records=grid.getStore().getUpdatedRecords();
        for(i=0;i<records.length;i++){
        alert(records[i].get('name'));
        alert(records[i].get('units'));
        var s=records[i].get('name')+','+records[i].get('units');
        alert(s);
    }
      }


   }],


 });


   Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
      renderTo: Ext.getBody(),  
      items: [
     {
      width:600,
      height:500,
      layout:'fit',
      items:[grid
      ]
    }
  ]
});
});
```

Comment: The error is not because of that line.

Comment: I commmented that line and the eror was gone

Comment: You may add alert(record) inside renderer just to check if record is really undefined. I guess you have problem with grid object

Comment: Yes it is defined. The application is running fine. This error is only in the console. It does not affect functionality. Just curious to know what this error is all about.

Comment: I guess it could be an internal Ext thing.

Comment: Any suggestions to resolve this?